# How to create a light sheen/gradient with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-reproduction

I am trying to replicate the slight matte/sheen effect seen on this blue Visa card graphic, and was wondering what would be the best approach to replicate a color gradient such as this.

[image]

I used to eyedropper tool and tried to determine whether there was a pattern to the way the colors were distributed (i.e a circle, fade towards top, a "light" source towards the top etc) but could not find any real patterns. Any guidance is much apprenticed - thanks!

Comment: If you burn the heck out of it, you can see it a bit better. [I used Curves to do that.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/48WmN.png)

Comment: Whoa - nice trick. Thank you and great stuff :)

Comment: You can use a radial gradient or soft brush to do it, too.

Comment: @daspianist learn this simple technique (realted to Joonas' comment) https://fstoppers.com/originals/how-make-sure-your-pictures-are-clean-possible-60014 to determine such subtle areas